# Minimum excluded number

Tags: code-golf, math

This is intended to be an easy, bite-size code-golf.

The [mex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mex_(mathematics)) (minimal excluded number) of a finite collection of numbers is the smallest non-negative integer `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...` that does *not* appear in the collection. In other words, it's the minimum of the complement. The mex operation is central to the analysis of [impartial games](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impartial_game) in [combinatorial game theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_game_theory).

Your goal is to write a *program* or *named function* to compute the mex using as few bytes as possible.

**Input:**

A list of non-negative integers in any order. May contain repeats. For concreteness, the length of the list and the allowed range of elements will both be between `0` and `20` inclusive.

The definition of "list" here is flexible. Any structure that represents a collection of numbers is fine, as long as it has a fixed ordering of elements and allows repeats. It may not include any auxiliary information except its length.

The input can be taken as a function argument or through STDIN.

**Output**

The smallest excluded number. Output or print it.

**Test cases**

```
[1]
0
[0]
1
[2, 0]
1
[3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3]
2
[]
0
[1, 2, 3]
0
[5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7]
3
[3, 2, 1, 0]
4
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]
4
[1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 11, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18]
10
```

Comment: Restricting the numbers to a fixed range makes this problem even simpler.

Comment: @MartinBüttner If the array contains all number `0` to `20`, the correct output is 21. I'll add a test case. Yes, the fixed range definitely makes it easier, though one could still arguably use `sys.maxint` or `2**64` if I didn't specify it.

Comment: No need for that test case. You said, the input can only contain 21 elements.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Right, fencepost. Thanks.

Comment: @xnor I cannot expect input array already on stack, can I ? :P

Comment: @Optimizer Nope.

Comment: @MartinBüttner - I read ***"**.. the **length of the list** and the allowed range of elements will both be **between 0 and 20 inclusive"*** to mean that the list will have at most 20 elements. So, the highest output would be ***20***, given a list of all numbers starting with ***0*** and ending with ***19***. Am I wrong?

Comment: @KevinFegan Yes, the maximum possible output is 20. My comment was mistaken and I think MartinBüttner typoed.

Answer (score 10):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
h-U21Q
```

## Example run

```
$ pyth -c h-U21Q <<< '[5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7]'
3
```

#### How it works

```
  U21   range(21)
     Q  eval(input())
 -U21Q  setwisedifference(range(21), eval(input))          # Pyth function. Preserves order.
h-U21Q  setwisedifference(range(21), eval(input))[0]
```

Comment: When the set is converted to list, is it always in sorted order?

Comment: Pyth's set difference preserves the order of the first argument (`range(21)`), which is ordered. (This also means the explanation isn't entirely accurate. Pyth and Python 3 are both fairly new to me.)

Comment: To clarify, `-` in Pyth is actually a filter - it filters the first argument for absence from the second argument, then converts it to the form of the first argument (string, list or set).

Comment: Also, Dennis, it should be `h-U22Q` so it will give the correct output of 21 on the input containing the full allowable range.

Comment: @isaacg: The list's length is also limited to 20, so it cannot contain all 21 numbers from 0 to 20.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I should have read that more carefully.

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, <s>11</s> 8 bytes

```
K),l~^1<
```

How it works:

```
K),         "Create an array with numbers 0 through 20"
   l~       "Read the input and eval it, resulting to an array"
     ^      "XOR the elements of two arrays, resulting in a complement array"
      1<    "Take the first element of the resultant array"
```

Sample input:

```
[1 0 7 6 3 11 15 1 9 2 3 1 5 2 3 4 6 8 1 18]
```

Output:

```
10
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Comment: How high do the single-character numbers in CJam go?

Comment: @xnor Sadly, 20 - https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam/wiki/Variables/

Comment: A lucky choice!

Answer (score 5):

## J - 13 char

```
f=:0{i.@21&-.
```

Very simple actions in J, and thus very hard to make smaller.

`i.@21` creates a list from 0 to 20 inclusive. `-.` performs set-subtracts the input from this list. `0{` takes the first element of what's left, i.e. the smallest number. `f=:` defines a named function. At the REPL:

```
   f=:0{(i.21)&-.
   f 1
0
   f 0
1
   f 2 0
1
   f 3 1 0 1 3 3
2
   f ''    NB. empty list
0
   f 1 2 3
0
   f 5 4 1 5 4 8 2 1 5 4 0 7 7
3
   f 3 2 1 0
4
   f 0 0 1 1 2 2 3
4
   f 1 0 7 6 3 11 15 1 9 2 3 1 5 2 3 4 6 8 1 18
10
```

Since the release of J806 in November 2017, a new syntax exists which saves us one byte by letting us use `i.@21` for the old `(i.21)` in this context.

Comment: Do you need `f=:`?

Comment: Since November 2017 `i.@21-.]` would save 1 byte.

Answer (score 5):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 4 bytes

```
ℕ≜¬∈
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HL1Eedcw6tedTR8f9/1P9oQx0FAx0Fcx0FMx0FYx0FQyDf0BSIdRQsdRSMIGI6CqYwtglYoQVY0NAiFgA)

Works for any list size and any integer magnitudes.

Takes input from the Output variable, and outputs to the Input variable.

#### Explanation

```
ℕ      We want a non-negative integer
 ≜     Assign a value such that… 
  ¬∈   …it is not an element of the list
```

Comment: Oddly enough, it looks like [the `≜` can be dropped going the other way](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HnwkeN@x@1TP3/P9pQR8FAR8FcR8FMR8FYR8EQyDc0BWIdBUsdBSOImI6CKYxtAlZoARY0tIj9HwUA).

Comment: ...Actually, the original version can handle an empty list, while this can't. Whoops

Comment: @UnrelatedString Reverted.

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
0ḟ1#
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/g4Y75hsr/D7c/alrz/380F2e0YawOkDQAk0Y6ChCGsY6CIZANJoFsY7AgmAAKGMEETHUUTMBKIAwLsBScC9RtDkQw8yBSEOMNYGZDTIMbaAjTZQa21hCkwhSsyhKiCmY8hG0CVmgBMckilisWAA)

Doesn't use the bounds on the input.

...am I missing something?

```
0       Starting with 0,
  1#    find the first integer
 ḟ      which is not in the input.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Golfscript 7

```
~21,^0=
```

A further-golfed version of Peter Taylor's answer. Community wiki since I don't have the rep to comment on his post.

The difference is using the known max list size from the question instead of length +1 to save a character and dropping the irrelevant $.

[Try it online](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydbNSA0IDEgNSA0IDggMiAxIDUgNCAwIDcgN10nCgp%2BMjEsXjA9)

Comment: Dammit Golfscript for saving 1 character so as to not read the input -_-

Answer (score 4):

## Bash+coreutils, 23 bytes

```
seq 0 20|egrep -vwm1 $1
```

This assumes input as a `|` (pipe) separated list.  E.g:

```
$ ./mex.sh "5|4|1|5|4|8|2|1|5|4|0|7|7"
3
$
```

Comment: I don't think you need `"(...)"` around the `$1`.

Comment: Pipe-separated is fine, it meets the list-like condition of the spec.

Comment: If you take input separated by newlines, you can use `grep` instead of `egrep`

Answer (score 4):

## [Burlesque](http://mroman.ch/burlesque/) -  9 Bytes

```
20rzj\\<]
```

Takes input from stdin in the format {7 6 5 5 1 2 2 4 2 0}

Explained:

```
 20 rz   map a range from 0 to 20. (thanks to algorithmshark for the cocde fix)
  j \\    swaps the two arrays, and collects the difference between the two into a new array
  <]      gets the smallest element of the resulting array.
```

Try some examples:

[{1 0 7 6 3 11 15 1 9  2 3 1 5 2 3 4 6 8 1 18}20rzj\\<]](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=%7B1+0+7+6+3+11+15+1+9+2+3+1+5+2+3+4+6+8+1+18%7D20rzj%5C%5C%3C%5D)

[{5 4 1 5 4 8 2 1 5 4 0 7 7}20rzj\\<]](http://eso.mroman.ch/cgi/burlesque.cgi?q=%7B5%204%201%205%204%208%202%201%205%204%200%207%207%7D20rzj%5C%5C%3C%5D)

Comment: This fails to give any output on the input `{0 1 2}`, because you need to `rz` one more than the largest number. Just going straight for `20rzj\\<]` fixes this and saves a char.

Comment: @algorithmshark No way around it, you are very right. Fixed. And thank you.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Ṁ‘‘Ḷḟ⁸Ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#PY27DYAwDERrmCIDpCCET5gFZRegYQU6JGpqFGomSRYJ5iwjWafL@fyS4z2laaOJ4YphT3OI4cjPmpYz57EsRuM1aQWttWJjtTLkoeQtQggFtQStVg0qbBxW/5Ouexrh8YrxlbCZ9gONXHX41nyNFq2BW4Jn36DomOR86V8)

### How it works

```
Ṁ‘‘Ḷḟ⁸Ḣ  Main Link; argument is z
Ṁ‘‘      Takes 2 above the largest element in z
   Ḷ     Takes lowered range (thus returning [0, ..., max(z) + 1])
    ḟ⁸   Exclude all elements from the range that are also in z
      Ḣ  Take the first element (which is the smallest)
```

Thanks to @LeakyNun for -1 byte!

Comment: [1 byte off](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#PY27DYAwDERrmCIDpCCET5gFZRegYQU6JGpqFGomSRYJ5iwjWafL@fyS4z2laaOJ4YphT3OI4cjPmpYz57EsRuM1aQWttWJjtTLkoeQtQggFtQStVg0qbBxW/5Ouexrh8YrxlbCZ9gONXHX41nyNFq2BW4Jn36DomOR86V8)

Answer (score 4):

## [Trilangle](https://github.com/bbrk24/Trilangle/), 53 bytes

```
'0.<_.\.>?0e#L_'\r/(&\,<.|.1.2S<.^#':2',.<..^\,!@.^)S
```

I'm not convinced this is optimal, but I've thought about it for a while and I don't think I can shrink it without substantial restructuring. I have proven that it's impossible to do this general approach without at *least* a grid of size n=8, and this is n=10.

Try it on [the online interpreter](https://bbrk24.github.io/Trilangle/?i=1%200%207%206%203%2011%2015%201%209%202%203%201%205%202%203%204%206%208%201%2018#%270.%3C_.%5C.%3E%3F0e%23L_%27%5Cr%2F(%26%5C%2C%3C.%7C.1.2S%3C.%5E%23%27%3A2%27%2C.%3C..%5E%5C%2C!%40.%5E)S)!

Unfolds to this:

```
         '
        0 .
       < _ .
      \ . > ?
     0 e # L _
    ' \ r / ( &
   \ , < . | . 1
  . 2 S < . ^ # '
 : 2 ' , . < . . ^
\ , ! @ . ^ ) S . .
```

[image]

Equivalent to this C code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

// Read an integer from stdin, throwing out any separators. Returns -1 on EOF.
// Exact implementation is unimportant (and provided by the interpreter).
extern int getint(void);

int main() {
    // RED PATH
    // Keep a bitfield of the numbers that have been seen so far
    int field = 0;
    int i;
    while ((i = getint()) >= 0)
        // GREEN PATH
        field |= 1 << i;

    // BLUE PATH
    // Find the lowest nonzero bit
    int missing = 0;
    while (field & 1) {
        // MAGENTA PATH
        field >>= 1;
        ++missing;
    }

    // YELLOW PATH
    printf("%d\n", missing);
}
```

I am not doing an instruction-by-instruction walkthrough of this code. If you're interested, you can look into the disassembly feature of the interpreter.

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `gH`, 2 bytes

```
ʀ⊍
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJnQUgiLCIiLCLKgOKKjSIsIiIsIlsxXVxuWzBdXG5bMiwgMF1cblszLCAxLCAwLCAxLCAzLCAzXVxuW11cblsxLCAyLCAzXVxuWzUsIDQsIDEsIDUsIDQsIDgsIDIsIDEsIDUsIDQsIDAsIDcsIDddXG5bMywgMiwgMSwgMF1cblswLCAwLCAxLCAxLCAyLCAyLCAzXVxuWzEsIDAsIDcsIDYsIDMsIDExLCAxNSwgMSwgOSwgMiwgMywgMSwgNSwgMiwgMywgNCwgNiwgOCwgMSwgMThdIl0=) (Includes test cases)

```
   # H flag presets the stack to 100
ʀ  # inclusive range 0..100
 ⊍ # set difference
   # g flag takes the minimum of the top of stack after execution
   # which is implicitly output
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 2 bytes

```
ᵏf
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6Fksebu1PW1KclFwMFVhwc2e0YSxXtAEQG-kogChjHQVDIAtMAtnGQCEgAnKMIBxTHQUTsCSEYQGWgHOB-syBCGIORAJkqAHMRIg5UKMMYerNwFYZguRNwWosIWpgBkPYJmCFFhBzLGIhPgAA)

```
ᵏf
ᵏ   Find the first natural number n such that:
 f  the input does not contain n
```

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, 32 bytes

```
f=->n{(0..20).find{|i|n-[i]==n}}
```

Defines a function `f` to be called with an array.

Comment: Any comments from the downvoter? Did I miss some part of the spec?

Comment: I doubt it. Several other answers (including mine) got a mystery downvote.

Comment: @ipi but it does... in exactly the same format given in the examples in the challenge posts, e.g. `f[[0, 1]]` (where the outer brackets are invocation syntax and the inner brackets define the array).

Comment: Why do you need the `f=`?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

Another approach. Can be used in a chain with any arity, and doesn't need chain separator or anything.

```
‘Ṭ;0i0’
```

Because the answer is guaranteed to be less than 256, this also works:

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
⁹ḶḟµḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9qZWxsef//4oG54bi24bifwrXhuKL///9bMCwxLDIsMyw1LDdd)

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>18</s> 16 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to nwellnhof*

```perl6
{(0...*∉@_)-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1rDQE9PT@tRR6dDvKauYe3/4sRKhTSNaAMdQx0jHWMdEx3TWE1rLiRRBQWcokCx/wA)

Anonymous code block that counts up until it finds a number that is not an element of the input list, and returns the length of the range minus one

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
Jr,╓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7/9@rSOfR1Mn//0cb6JjrGOoY6RjrWOiY6JjFAgA)

This solution is restricted to just the range 0 to 20, though this can be extended easily by increasing the initial range.

#### Explanation:

```
Jr     Range from 0 to 20
  ,    Remove elements from the input list from this range
   ╓   Return the minimum element
```

Alternatively, a 5 byte solution for all numbers:

```
Åï╧▲ï
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9tYXRoZ29sZv//w4XDr@KVp@KWssOv//9bMCw3LDEsMiwzLDgsNCw2XQ)

#### Explanation:

```
Å  ▲   Do while true
  ╧    Does the input contain
 ï     The index of the loop?
    ï  Push the number of iterations of the last loop
```

Comment: With the new changes that are (hopefully) being added to TIO today, there's a 4 byte solution to this problem. It is restricted to an upper limit defined in the code, but since MathGolf has a 1-byte literal for 10^8, it shouldn't be noticeable.

Comment: This was the exact solution I had (I used `Z` instead of `J` because I was lazy).

Answer (score 3):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), <s>117, 113, 79</s> 78 bytes

```rust
|l:&[u8]|{let mut r:Vec<_>=(0..22).collect();r.retain(|n|!l.contains(n));r[0]}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVK7boMwFJW6ma8wGSJboggT0tCkaZfOHbsgFCFkJCTitNh0Ab6kS4b2o9qv6bUN6YMMtZCx7zn3nGPpvr7VjVTHz4v7QuB9VgpCces4qOIKKy7VLs8kl3iLEwcPi7zw3E1Y6uGAen-qAVTZpBoC9SywgCJgZofzAkjhhHTWCBpC2zDFlh6OjKQ9xIZ6uoLbCj7oXJzLY6k6bjR93ZjVug8BfvEchJDhnkp6ITb6XpmHMq2xNDrXVmcMaM-RIcbWK_YcNAqlnjZgAez_cA3GpFZyaVRXRhhsWTAE0U_WAaIhFJDYyhhjpuMFkwAh-w6QboZxKfD2vVHFZfzx0FXredLEaddqYN8oXK8feX6zu92SwPfDkPr5oap4rgjd1H7NlZ68TnRuBYDQN0kEBQwmqh9US7RxUHGoMdEz6eFMSIpL8XNMW4iVSclrtePPLinIXNep5UI3eqpLoSrhkhlgrQbXdz2F8W6B0c80p3cGw-PR_r8A)

### Explanation

```rust
|l: &[u8]| {
    // Make a vector of the integers from 0 to 21
    let mut r: Vec<_> = (0..22).collect();
    // Keep only the numbers that aren't in the input
    r.retain(|n|!l.contains(n));
    // Return the first remaining number in the vector
    r[0]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

Thanks to [@fhuvi](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/116582/fhuvi) for letting me know that [my answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258384/58563) to [this more recent challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258335/58563) also works here.

```javascript
a=>a.reduce(m=>m+a.includes(m),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLRDoIgFIbvewouYZGCWtmFvkjjgiE2m0rT7PWJILuwrKkxxs7Z2Pef859z5jfeiqa4XDe1yqTOE82TlHuNzDohYZWk1Zp7RS3KLpMtrBAmSAtVt6qUXqlOMIdHysCCgxDwfUBWAyj5A5QOoQEGC7gj0BADarj2NXHIZkCDIXRR92OemgKDyQX@gm4xiGzvLoitxis1tuzNZd@h4QdPHWXWuBw0elupfkrOh4lWjEBp3@POTp8@8FsrcXASvRkujuzH2JURs@dKEX0H)

Answer (score 2):

### GolfScript (<strike>10</strike> 9 bytes)

```
~.,),^$0=
```

Takes input from stdin in the format `[5 4 1 5 4 8 2 1 5 4 0 7 7]`.

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=OydbNSA0IDEgNSA0IDggMiAxIDUgNCAwIDcgN10nCgp%2BLiwpLF4kMD0%3D)

Comment: Shouldn't the `;` before the input string be counted in the program itself ?

Comment: @Optimizer, that's simulating input from stdin because the online GolfScript site doesn't support a separate input field.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 22

```
x=->n{([*0..20]-n)[0]}
```

### Explanation

- Input is taken as an argument to a lambda. It expects an `Array` of `Integer`s.
- The input is subtracted from the array `[0,1,2..20]`.
- Because the `Array` `[0,1,2..20]` is sorted, the first element must be the mex.

Comment: Sweet, that was my first attempt, but I couldn't get the destructuring to work - I didn't think of surrounding it with brackets. Btw, you can use `20` instead of `21`, because the input can only contain 20 elements.

Answer (score 2):

## Xojo, 55 bytes

```
dim x as int8
while a.indexOf(x)>-1
x=x+1
wend
return x
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 30

```
f s=filter(`notElem`s)[0..]!!0
```

This works for lists of all size and lists beyond 20. This can be made 15 bytes long if Data.List is imported:

```
f s=[0..]\\s!!0
```

Answer (score 2):

### Scheme - 219

```
(define (A X) (define (B X) (if (equal? (length X) 1) (+ (car X) 1) (if (< (- (cadr X) (car X)) 2) (B (cdr X)) (+ (car X) 1)))) (if (empty? X) `() (if (equal? (car (sort X <)) 0) (B (sort X <)) (- (car (sort X <)) 1))))
```

Not very competitive. But I like writing scheme :),

Here's the ungolfed code:

```
(define (minExclude X)
  (define (firstNonOneDifference X)
     (if (equal? (length X) 1)
         (+ (car X) 1)
     (if (< (- (cadr X) (car X)) 2) 
         (firstNonOneDifference (cdr X))
         (+ (car X) 1)
     ))
  )
  (let ([s (sort X <)])
     (if (empty? X)
         `()
     (if (equal? (car s) 0)
        (firstNonOneDifference s)
        (- (car s) 1)
     ))
  )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

## R, 27 bytes

Reads from stdin; computes the first element in the set difference between `[0..20]` and `x`.

```
x=scan()
setdiff(0:20,x)[1]
```

## R, 36 bytes

`which.min(y%in%x)` returns the index of the first element of `y` that is not in `x`.

```
x=scan()
y=0:20
y[which.min(y%in%x)]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 28 bytes

```perl
$#i++;/\b$#i\b/&&redo;$_=$#i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19FOVNb21o/JgnIiEnSV1MrSk3Jt1aJtwXy//83VrBQMFQwUDBRMFIwVzD7l19QkpmfV/xftwAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, 28 bytes

```powershell
for(;+$i-in$args){$i++}+$i
```

Test script:

```powershell
$f = {
 for(;+$i-in$args){$i++}+$i
#for(;$i++-in$args){}(--$i)   # alternative version
}

@(
    ,(0 , 1)
    ,(1 , 0)
    ,(2 , 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3)
    ,(0 )
    ,(0 , 1, 2, 3)
    ,(3 , 5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7)
    ,(4 , 3, 2, 1, 0)
    ,(4 , 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
    ,(10, 1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 11, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18)
) | % {
    $e, $a = $_
    $r = &$f @a
    "$($r-eq$e): $r"
}
```

Output:

```powershell
True: 0
True: 1
True: 2
True: 0
True: 0
True: 3
True: 4
True: 4
True: 10
```

Explanation:

- Increment `$i` while the `$args` array contains the integer value `+$i`.
- Output a last integer value `+$i`.

Comment: Can be shortened down to [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9Py2/SMNaJVNbWzczTyWxKL1Ys7pWJVPX8H8tF5eaSpqCgYKhgpGCsYKJgul/AA "PowerShell Core – Try It Online") :)

Answer (score 2):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), <s>64</s> 35 bytes

*-29 bytes thanks to [@Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/76162/jo-king)*

```
L+X:-between(0,20,X),\+member(X,L).
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/LCoMwEEV/JbhKcFLiq7UuBPd@QCDNQiEtgo@ggjt/3Y5JLUwyd3JvToidp3768GXrjqMOZcFbs27GjFRALEAyeIWDGVozUwk1ux0FHxrbd8tKVaXLklahhPc0D81Kg90SXpLd7mMAqgKpGQOlIg1K4IqBnC0BEqFyO@oEj7BwiP2QAUmd6UXujP@I9x5YnuONEyououf8UNGVv7unotPPXObpMxfY69QFc8/JtcbffgE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <s>7</s> <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
₇ʀFg
```

*-2 bytes thanks to lyxal*

*-1 byte thanks to Steffan*

[Try it online](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLigofKgCRGZyIsIiIsIlszLCAxLCAwLCAxLCAzLCAzXSJd) or [verify all test cases](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJyQSIsIiIsIuKCh8qARmciLCIiLCJbMV1cblswXVxuWzIsIDBdXG5bMywgMSwgMCwgMSwgMywgM11cbltdXG5bMSwgMiwgM11cbls1LCA0LCAxLCA1LCA0LCA4LCAyLCAxLCA1LCA0LCAwLCA3LCA3XVxuWzMsIDIsIDEsIDBdXG5bMCwgMCwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgM11cblsxLCAwLCA3LCA2LCAzLCAxMSwgMTUsIDEsIDksIDIsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDYsIDgsIDEsIDE4XSJd).

Explanation:

```
 ʀ    # The range 0 to
₇     # 128
  F   # Filter out items from the range that are in the input list
      # (The r flag swaps the arguments)
    g  # Get the lowest one
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oKHyoAkRmciLCIiLCJbMV1cblswXVxuWzIsIDBdXG5bMywgMSwgMCwgMSwgMywgM11cbltdXG5bMSwgMiwgM11cbls1LCA0LCAxLCA1LCA0LCA4LCAyLCAxLCA1LCA0LCAwLCA3LCA3XVxuWzMsIDIsIDEsIDBdXG5bMCwgMCwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgM11cblsxLCAwLCA3LCA2LCAzLCAxMSwgMTUsIDEsIDksIDIsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDYsIDgsIDEsIDE4XSJd) for 5 bytes

Comment: [Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4oKHyoAkRmciLCIiLCJbMV1cblswXVxuWzIsIDBdXG5bMywgMSwgMCwgMSwgMywgM11cbltdXG5bMSwgMiwgM11cbls1LCA0LCAxLCA1LCA0LCA4LCAyLCAxLCA1LCA0LCAwLCA3LCA3XVxuWzMsIDIsIDEsIDBdXG5bMCwgMCwgMSwgMSwgMiwgMiwgM11cblsxLCAwLCA3LCA2LCAzLCAxMSwgMTUsIDEsIDksIDIsIDMsIDEsIDUsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDYsIDgsIDEsIDE4XSJd) for test cases

Comment: @lyxal Smart, thank you

Comment: 4 bytes with `r` flag: `Þ∞Fh`

Comment: @Steffan That doesn't work for the `[1]` test case, but you can just remove the `$` and from Lyxal's one and add the `r` flag

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 9 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 7.41 bytes

```
21RAq0sAh
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhYrjQyDHAsNih0zIHyo8IKb9tGGOgoGOgrmOgpmOgrGOgqGQL6hKRDrKFjqKBhBxHQUTGFsE7BCC7CgoUUsxBwA)

##### Explanation

```python
21RAq0sAh  # Implicit input                     INPUT: [4, 1, 0, 2]
21R        # Push range(21)                     STACK: [4, 1, 0, 2], [0..20]
   Aq      # Check whether each of the items    STACK: [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
           # in the input occurs in range(21)
     0sAh  # Find the index of the first 0      STACK: 3
           # (0-indexed)
           # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 22 bytes

```julia
>(x,i=0)=i∈x?x>i+1:i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@//fTqNCJ9PWQNM281FHR4V9hV2mtqFV5n9lBdeKxNyCnFQuh@KM/HIFO41oQx0FIx0F41hNLi5lhZDU4pJiLofE4uLUohKwbKymgq2tggGymAFEzBBZDGgENmFjHQWg@QZg0hhsC0iJEbISLBbAnYQhY6qjYAI2DMKwACuEc4H2mAMRRJ8xmjsgCqGONEHxD8yFEHsRVpugOQpivhnYK4Yg9aZgPZYQPTCHQNgmYIUWEHMtoEFj8B8A)

Minimally adapted from [MarcMush's recursive solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/258847/114865) to a [related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/258335/114865).

Julia 0.6 supports ternary operators without spaces, which were deprecated in 0.7 and removed in 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, 37 characters

```python
f=lambda a:min(set(range(21))-set(a))
```

Comment: Beat me by a couple of seconds. BTW, it's `range(21)`.

Comment: This seems to be the shortest solution. The recursive solution `f=lambda l,i=0:i in l and f(l,i+1)or i` is one char longer and the iterative solution `i=0;l=input()\nwhile i in l:i+=1\nprint i` is two chars longer (not storing the input makes it be taken repeatedly). Without the `20` bound, I think these approaches would prevail.

Comment: Couldn't this be an anonymous function? If it could, you can save 2 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

**C# - 64 chars**

```
int f(int[] a){return Enumerable.Range(0,20).Except(a).First();}
```

<s>Not always</s> Rarely the best golfing language, but is easy to write and understand :)

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 18 bytes

```
0 to 20 diff l min
```

`l` is a list of Int.

```
scala> val l = List(0,1,5)
l: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 5)

scala> 0 to 20 diff l min
res0: Int = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 38 Bytes

```
<?=min(array_diff(range(0,20),$_GET));
```

### PHP, 39 Bytes

```
<?for(;in_array($i++,$_GET););echo$i-1;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```
int c(java.util.List a){int r=0;for(;a.contains(r);r++);return r;}
```

-3 bytes thanks to *@LeakyNun*

**Explanation:**

Supports not only 0-20, but 0-2147483647 instead (which actually saves bytes).

```
int c(java.util.List a){    // Method with List parameter and integer return-type
  int r=0;                  //  Return integer
  for(;a.contains(r);r++);  //  Continue raising `r` as long as the list contains the current `r`
  return r;                 //  Return result-integer
}                           // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lZFNS8QwEIbv/RVzTNgS2v3QSvDgXU97FA8xVom0SUmmK8vS317zsV0RRA2EMEneed6ZieoHYxHexUGwEVXH7qwVx3vlkBfqxzfHC9kJ5@DhVAA4FKgkzEojSPIlDQQQ9BTu7W3FX40lXDBpNAqlHbGU29XKby2OVoPl0wwwjM@dh52ZB6NeoPdqsker9NvjUwB6T4D90WHbMzMiG/wTdppIkqpjwgVvUlNK@X/FVY54XUKWflNC7VPi7uPN77m6/YDLH5AcH49f/4n/nrIrYRvrSkETCZejL/nar8xeEyFrQtUyntRCbhf1UupVHHAdQLsIu0mwpacUb6OwSYbN2WgqpvkT)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
class M{
  static int c(java.util.List a){int r=0;for(;a.contains(r);r++);return r;}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(1)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(0)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(2, 0)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3)));
    System.out.println(c(new ArrayList()));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(3, 2, 1, 0)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3)));
    System.out.println(c(Arrays.asList(1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 11, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18)));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
0
1
1
2
0
0
3
4
4
10
```

Comment: [Heh, libraries](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118291/48934).

Comment: [3 bytes off](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#lZFNS8QwEIbv/RVzTNgS2v3QSvDgXU97FA@xVhlpk5JMV5alv72myXZFEDUQwiR553lnJtj1xhK8q4MSA2Er7qxVx3t0JDP88c3JrG6Vc/BwygAcKcIaJtQENfuSzgRQ/DTf420hX41lUonaaFKoHUMucbXi0jY0WA0oxwmgH55bDzszDwZfoPNqtieL@u3xaQZ6T4D90VHTCTOQ6P0TtZrVLFYnlJu9Wck5l/8VFynidQ5J@k0OpU8Ju483v@fq5gMuf8BSfDx@/Sf@e8ouh22oKwZVIFyOvuRrvxJ7jYSkCRXLeGILqV2US6lXYcDlDNoF2E2ELT3FeBuEVTSszkZjNk6f)

Answer (score 1):

## [Java](http://openjdk.java.net/), 91 bytes

```java
int f(int[]a){int i=0,j=1,k;for(;j>0;i++)for(k=j=0;k<a.length;j=a[k++]==i?1:j);return i-1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#nVDLboQgFF13voKlRGpgHq1TSvsFXc3SuKBTdVAHDWCbxvjtFiF2jwm53BM4j3v74bMVV3Btudbggws5zkIaUEa2ZjmH44IEw6hmBDW07FRE6zdMRRzDBTSsZpg2rzxpC1mZG60Zz5o4zhkT7@SlhlQVZlASiEdCp7n3dtpwY6/vTnyBuzWNLkYJWWU54KrScNw9XH61Ke5JN5ikt0@mlZEsflzCCCalAy7iSCYIaQgBhxL2CARzDggQS3PV9odQfuh/a7PfYHNC4Ogy@iZ1Kv/Qxn@2Z8PsXiV4a3hdmR9ny0Rkjf3kFk8WsZMTPHvBdT7fH93H1JumzmzaTfMf)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 19 bytes

```apl
(0⍳⍨⊢=⍳∘⍴)∘(⊂∘⍋⌷⊢)∪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#JUy7DsIwDNz5CkssZUEOaWkYGDIy8U8MCBWCWJCYOyHEBhL/4x8Jd@7g8z18ni/tet/t7XjTmoGNWvlYedowbslODyvfBVZjw8HV2S4/pPBetWYJsyyKWTlGCaKYKBHKyhsYkFF10oITE5yJqfTSe48OP6j32ZlawW/W/Ay7g94w8T53iyyxkf4)

I am probably missing out something important here. Golfing in progress...

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 24 bytes

```
:0→A                 //Store 0 to A
:Prompt X            //Prompt list X
:While not(prod(ʟX-A //While A is not missing from list X
:A+1→A               //Increment A
:End                 //End While loop
:A                   //Print A
```

If `Prompt X` is given a list instead of a single number, it will automatically create a list named `X` that can be accessed with `ʟX`.

Comment: 20 bytes using Ans: `Prompt X:0:While not(prod(ʟX-Ans:Ans+1:End:Ans`

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```bash
@!UøXÃa
@    Ãa # Starting from zero, find the smallest integer
 !UøX   # that's not present in the input array.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/30Ex9PCOiMPNif//RxvoGOoY65jomMYCAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¢╔⌂♀╠▬
```

[Run and debug it](http://stax.tomtheisen.com/#p=9bc97f0ccc16&i=[1]%0A[0]%0A[2,0]%0A[3,1,0,1,3,3]%0A[]%0A[1,2,3]%0A[5,4,1,5,4,8,2,1,5,4,0,7,7]%0A[3,2,1,0]%0A[0,0,1,1,2,2,3]%0A[1,0,7,6,3,11,15,1,9,2,3,1,5,2,3,4,6,8,1,18]&m=2)

**Explanation**

```
21r:IUI             # Full program, unpacked
21                  # Push 21
  r                 # Range from 0...20
   :I               # Find all elements in input that exist in range
    U               # push -1
     I              # Get index of first occurrence of
```

Answer (score 1):

### F#, 38 bytes

```
let f s={0..20}|>Seq.except s|>Seq.min
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVHLasMwELz7KxZDoIXG2Hm0KWp8Kb31UEhvIQfjSLHAll1pExyafnuqRyw5EIx2dmZ2d8LUtGwlvV5risBArX/TJJmlf5d8Q38S2pe0Q1CuarhwNC4VflOFsIZttosMpmjZiv0Apg7EikuPzQjcYNYeJVYDPieQ6Zb96vf8xuHMUz65woQ2HZ7dKN4HtRbNvEjRExWhtySwsLbusbJUX@qJL/rnlJQfKhxt5Ii3fQUfmabDrm5yGI7j0dng/2yPygx/aTWvTjMs4t4LS1w539UusoZFXRs7Zfx85GSUNAkBk1GoJIRHQlhknA4JB5NwHgk36BWi7duHQHn@anU/dzc2BRdQyMMJ1pGeKLVA4XuhKBh82HffRuD@tKbo4IEdBfQwzUGh5OIA/WOQXXLYWDTRR5UFQvwEsUE7DSITEG8nahdrP3Yn8u0JN01f6iK9/gM)

Fairly straight-forward to be honest...

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 92 bytes

```
x=function(a,...)q=...or 0 for i=0,#a do if a[i]==q then return x(a,q+1)end end return q end
```

This seems *way* too long.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7dCsMgDIXv9xSB3VQmRfuzdRc@ydiFrC0Thq1ioTD27C7VtWAZxJATv5zkNUnvZ9FP@uHUoDNJ8zwnRmAeLDDoMSvB6FFCO4DqQd7UXQgD7tlpsJ2brIYZx8yJk063sLxf2yzCj1Zpl83Zm38IOWyKJaqgkDZKChx7FLAok59EIFPsgZpCFaZj0QRkk2h5wdgvi0h6Aws0D1H8WcRXt3M4ky9kHehrpNe1sa4C2ETHBp38Fw)

Comment: [88 bytes](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwDIbvPkXAy4o9LNvUeeiTiIfiNixIZ0sHA/HZa9q6QYeQlPzplz95TtL7WQyTvjs16kJyw4wwMFooYaBXCeR7Cd0IagAjhLyqm3v0GmzvJqthDiMHZL3uIOSvbYLwL6u0K@bijR/GdqsqM1VxyBs1B6QeByrq7CcTxFRb4MihidOpaCOySrI8U2yXJSS/oYw0xqj@LMLF7RTPxEAeI31J9LI21U0E2@TYkpP/Ag)

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

```apl
f←⊃⊢~⍨0,⍳∘⍴
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEddzY@6FtU96l1hoPOod/OjjhmPerf8f9Q3FSiXBqS4SGD@1zHk0jHgetS7hstARwGIDMHICIyMuQzBYuY6CmZAHlAGJGsKVmEJUQFmm8LYJmCFFhBTLAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 29 bytes

```
Min@Complement[0~Range~20,#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b73zczz8E5P7cgJzU3Na8k2qAuKDEvPbXOyEBHOVbtf1p0taGOgoGOgrmOgpmOgrGOgiGQb2gKxDoKljoKRhAxHQVTGNsErNACLGhoURv7/79uQVFmXgkA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 5 bytes

```
wiix#
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=wiix%23&i=[1]%0A[0]%0A[2,+0]%0A[3,+1,+0,+1,+3,+3]%0A[]%0A[1,+2,+3]%0A[5,+4,+1,+5,+4,+8,+2,+1,+5,+4,+0,+7,+7]%0A[3,+2,+1,+0]%0A[0,+0,+1,+1,+2,+2,+3]%0A[1,+0,+7,+6,+3,+11,+15,+1,+9,+2,+3,+1,+5,+2,+3,+4,+6,+8,+1,+18]&a=1&m=2)

```
w      run until condition is satisfied
 ii    push iteration index twice
   x#  number of times iteration index appears in input (non-zero is truthy)
```

When the loop is finished, the final iteration index will be on top of the main stack, and implicitly printed.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 36 bytes

```python
lambda a,i=0:i in a and f(a,i+1)or i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY/dCsIwDIWv7VPkbg4jtPvROpgvMntRGcOCdmPsxqevaboKJZzknHwly3d7zb4KU/8Ib/t5jhYsul52DpwHavwI05FGJ1XOK7gwUbXRGwZpEAYVS4WsawSFILmSruOMMwjV3rYIDftJaHb@La1e6e2s5DBZZmxCZZrKKxf@UMVAy6FbCmV20g0HdQJpYzpxWFbnNzoZivO9wHhqKUT4AQ)

Answer (score 1):

## [k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_(programming_language)), 7 bytes

```
*(!22)^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYw5EsMwDAN7vgKpImXsGVKHJecxKd24yP8rBWQKXksA9/6917rer/QoJX/W9UybyaZSoFJhUFZFlZTFULh0NCLvk/d/UwwMyv1W0TC52vUW34MhRtjJT@fh9Nn4m66fomFy1AkH8QnT8DGZlhYBB2xQDmOQ5vUD)

```
 (!22)  /[0, 1, 2, ..., 21]
      ^ /set difference between [0, 1, 2, ..., 21] and input (called exclude)
*       /get first element
```

For an arbitrary positive maximum instead of 20, the smallest I have so far is **13 bytes**:

```
{*(!2+|/x)^x}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 27 bytes

```factor
[ 21 iota swap diff first ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZFNDsIgEIX3nOJ5AQP90aoHMG7cGFfGRVNp0qhtBYwxDWevQ21aFy4oE2CAfMObmTzNTKXa42G3366h5eMpy0xq8ozGVapS3lAracy7VkVpsGGsYaDRQMDCf8zAe45P5ETPBZPIkQtJKacZklkPLui5KSp/8xOkNPSmRy5GRKxbE4rw9TiWZPYvFw75BV2G1vO/aOiDq4pT66N35ESnauHqSnhM51UXwSl2e0RviYucuKDUB84sa08IBIrKpNCvtMalyHPkhdIG5/ZOF/P2Aw)

```
       ! { 3 1 0 1 3 3 }
21     ! { 3 1 0 1 3 3 } 21
iota   ! { 3 1 0 1 3 3 } { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 }
swap   ! { 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 } { 3 1 0 1 3 3 }
diff   ! { 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 }
first  ! 2
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 52 bytes

```
L=[0...20]
f(l)=L[[(i-join(e,l))^2.minfori=L]>0].min
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2oau66cha7)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xqgoicgm3e)

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 31 bytes

```bash
for ((;$@[(I)$[i]];i++)):
bye i
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwc2FaflFCokKGlxKhkpcSgZAbKQAIo0VDBUMgNhYwRjIAyJDBSMw01TBBCgMIi2AIhCWgYK5gjlYE0gEpN0ArBmkB6LLEKzGDGicIVDYFChjCZIB6wfRJkA5C5AOCyUuTa7q4tQSBV1dBRXbRC6NpaUlaboW-0Hu1NCwVnGI1vDUVInOjI21ztTW1tS04kqqTFXIhKhaoWltY2OjYl8L4S5YAKEB)
Outputs via exit code.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
₂ÝIKн
```

-1 byte thanks to *@emanresuA*

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UVPT4bme3hf2/v8fbahjoGOuY6ZjrGNoqGNoqmOoY6ljBOLpmIJpE6CcBZBnaBELAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/R01Nh@dWel/Y@1/nf3S0YaxOtAEQG@mASGMdQx0DIDbWMQbygMhQxwjMNNUxAQqDSAugCIRloGOuYw7WBBIBaTcAawbpgegyBKsxAxpnCBQ2BcpYgmTA@kG0CVDOAqTDAqzZHKzVGCgElIiNBQA).

**Explanation:**

```python
₂Ý     # Push a list in the range [0,26]
       # (26 is the smallest 1-byte constant above 19)
  IK   # Remove all values of the input-list from this ranged list
    н  # Pop and push the first integer remaining (which is the minimum)
       # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: Would using a builtin number larger than 20 save bytes?

Comment: @emanresuA It indeed would, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@øX}f
```

[Try it here](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QPhYfWY&input=WzEgMCA3IDYgMyAxMSAxNSAxIDkgMiAzIDEgNSAyIDMgNCA2IDggMSAxOF0)

```
@øX}f     :Implicit input of array U
@         :Function taking an integer X as an argument
 øX       :  Does U contain X?
   }      :End function
    f     :First integer >=0 that returns false when passed through that function
```

### Japt [`-g`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 5 bytes

```
Lo kU
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LWc&code=TG8ga1U&input=WzEgMCA3IDYgMyAxMSAxNSAxIDkgMiAzIDEgNSAyIDMgNCA2IDggMSAxOF0)

```
Lo kU     :Implicit input of array U
L         :100
 o        :Range [0,L)
   kU     :Remove the elements of U
          :Implicit output of first element
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$5\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 4.116 bytes

```
[FxmN
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJbRnhtTiIsIls1LDQsMSw1LDQsOCwyLDEsNSw0LDAsNyw3XSJd)

Works for all numbers.

```
[FxmN
   mN # All natural numbers [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]
 Fx   # Remove the inputs
[     # Take the first one remaining
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 7 bytes

```
WiNgUii
```

Takes input as separate command-line arguments. [Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJwaXAiLCIiLCJXaU5nVWlpIiwiIiwiIiwiMSAwIDcgNiAzIDExIDE1IDEgOSAyIDMgMSA1IDIgMyA0IDYgOCAxIDE4Il0=)

#### Explanation

```
WiNgUii
W        While
 i       a number (initially 0)
  N      is an element of
   g     the list of command-line args:
    Ui     Increment the number
      i  Output the final value
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 26 bytes

```hs
f l=until(`notElem`l)(+1)0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzBDoIwDIZfpQcPEmuyMRA8cPToExASFgJKLHMRfH1nW5K1a79/355@fY1EKU1AzTdsMx378N5uNC49ZceTzUxa/ByggcXHO8TPHDY4yAITtK3tsDVcOUp3aNFwOXS88bGY61hiwVh6zWSfDFZYqSREdKOyOLtl9c2Fv7OMS06ukqgvd8FZLUatcqWqY8RB16XfMJF/rOk8xPgH)

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell + [hgl](https://gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 8 bytes

```haskell
he<bD nn
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ2W0km6Ec0CAUuxN1czcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRABXmm3M0tKSNF2LFRmpNkkuCnl5EO5NrdzEzDzblHwuBYWCIgUVhTSFaCMdYx0THQMdQx1LHRDbCMgz0zGKhehYsABCAwA)

### Explanation

- `bD nn` all non-negative integers not in the input
- `he` get the first.

### Reflection

This is a very straight-forward solution to a very simple problem. The only thing I might say is that it could possibly be worth having a built-in for "The smallest natural number such that ...". Assuming that would be 3 bytes the built in would save 2 bytes in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## x86_32 machine code, <sup><s>14</s></sup> 13 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to l4m2*

Expects the array in EDI (as a `uint8_t*`) and the length in ECX as an integer. Returns output in EAX.

```
31 c0 9e 60 f2 ae 61 75 03 40 eb f7 c3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVVtb9s2EP7OX3FIMcxKZEW209Sr6wJBlgwFshZoMKyobQSydLa4SKQgUrH7kt@eHUmJdrp5XyYkMsm7e@65N2qZqPwJ01zCEZstuVYwGi4Ym4BIVAklbiPz25dmJaG/wmI1GjKmMNVcCog0bjUDetaFXCYFpEmR3pHynTknmEspHrAmWKUTkSV1Bnw0Pje79L6/TBRmxqTgYg2pURUWVksP1IkJa6cQsX0/ry2BqlE5YMb3Nspt7KuUD0YaQraRxGKGqjoZUKhelm6fy86dzLj3ZHZwlaw8vl23jmvU7GkCmGynXGhv2CP5tKGT8Z0@BtGUKjQerU6BYq3zwIfkwtnK2qCE5gUTeG9yUkh5DysS9Ch/tYZEQxzsOE3gVssaITa6V9c3F7/dgpKgc9Lb5ChaT8AVfMVaAhUEVJqoJQikIkHdCBW2SJ@vjZpCbbCsNv1ScE1N1ckRqlpWxgRVU2joxUFkDVWSrxgjntWuKEnmmV1dfrJer359xzrKmNRpbqO6uAEu4JiEEbxbAdeQSVTiZw245UqHnf@LmwlwL@8Yc5HWWFJ/GBwbmkNO1gkXUVucSqALmXWVs@w@ojrEj4gQ3iZRIKQmmg2Je5@vp3Hg@ZBsg63I5KbkgpdN6Xz@Jb62evuF@kB69YYrDOEesTKVrajJnQlFYqruzEsnZMyBvO667OkI3lKzjIZmQBlrR/gF2RZNhvBG6YyaK8rf/nAmzRE7PYWPVG3fn5E5Waep6QGHmkI78tIdQf9PMwn9DzH01@tsCf1yNKSXyfHUzDRjLzJccUrw@z9@v7y4vbqFQUzEthopR/vDYGa21w1DaETBhDGjUVKpeg@SZwF8s4ESK@qMFCHDNPliVCW0ltA7DmaLTov6dykV0h1RVrYQBSe/SUFlQ8zolqF8o1X2U0htgGrWkV3AtPVpno7ebBF8GzyG/3oeHzgfhnBINAphQFL7pvXogNqBYzIaHjZ6GcKZBXaLsVX2W/L5iv4O83LKh4jHHWvH4T9oDDpf5zbEgbF5ae1@cXYdKbc@s4pjhz1@tJCPk3YMurvxhyp5GufWl0F0SOR1GO9Z47ai7xRmz833A4k7hDOXPWPtboaaAFa9@ZFsdNVo@O7B5nMxPwpaNXsZG1d8GtMV9KZzROuTk8AnyKP9lM01/RNCCF7aPc/mw3UnX4Q@B3xBV44PiXYth/YWiifskdGlsJtgxrqPuLsl/vEZ/78DH5061ae/AQ)

#### Explanation

```
; eax=int calc_mex(edi=uint8_t* nums, ecx=int length)
calc_mex:
  31 c0                   xor eax, eax ; N to look for (start at 0)
    
  ; Store 0 to EFLAGS so that when length is zero and scasb never runs,
  ; ZF is set to zero to return the proper result (0).
  9e                      sahf

loop:
  60                      pushad ; Store ECX and EDI

  ; Search for AL in *EDI. If it doesn't exist, return AL; if it does,
  ; increment AL and search again.
  f2 ae                   repne scasb

  61                      popad ; Restore ECX and EDI

  ; If AL was not found (ZF=0), return as we found the minimum.
  75 03                   jnz return
    
  ; Otherwise, keep looping.
  40                      inc eax
  eb f7                   jmp loop

return:
  c3                      ret
```

Comment: Why check `ecx` rather than `ZF`?

Comment: @l4m2 When `inc ecx` is removed and `jecxz` is converted to `jnz`, the empty list test case fails as `scasb` doesn't run and the jump is done based off of unrelated instructions (`xor eax, eax` on the first iteration and `inc eax` on the second). When `inc ecx` remains, test cases will fail randomly as `al` will occasionally be found in the extra checked byte.

Comment: [-1](https://tio.run/##PYzBDoIwDIbve4oe1eBFLwbDs5AyikC2stAtmb78HAztoWn/78@HImQ7874OKDalIHS/qScQxmZiDxqNbi3FE/VTE3LyaP0FOFipgHTpGOKXH8/q160V5InLulmqbe2B4Dgos7iCXZAR@/1cyTGBaJSuoMUdZOZPpj6svL8T679ttg6yTKnC68PkU/oC)

Answer (score 1):

### Pascal, 148 bytes

This is a complete `program` meeting the specifications of ISO standard 7185 “Standard Pascal”.
It expects a newline-separated possibly empty list of integers in the range `0..20`.

```pascal
program p(input,output);var i:0..20;s:set of 0..20;begin s:=[];while not EOF do begin readLn(i);s:=s+[i]end;i:=0;while i in s do i:=i+1;write(i)end.
```

Ungolfed:

```pascal
program minimumExcludedNumber(input, output);
    var
        i: 0..20;
        s: set of 0..20;
    begin
        { transform ordered list to “unordered” `set` ―――――――――――――――――――――― }
        
        { Initialize `s` as an empty set. }
        s := [];
        { This needs to be a head-controlled loop in order to
          take account of a possibly _empty_ list of integers. }
        while not EOF do
        begin
            readLn(i);
            s := s + [i]
        end;
        
        { analyze step: find first `integer` not part of set ――――――――――――――― }
        
        { Starting at zero “skip” all _included_ numbers in `s`. }
        i := 0;
        while i in s do
        begin
            { This is guaranteed not to cause an error [this concerns the case
              that `i` equals 20], because as per specification “the length of
              the list […] will […] be between 0 and 20 inclusive.” Specifying
              all integers in the interval `0..20` would require _21_ items. }
            i := i + 1
        end;
        write(i)
    end.
```

See also [natural supremum](/a/258504/94076) code golfing task and answer.

Answer (score 1):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 2.5 bytes (5 nibbles)

```
/-`,~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708LzMpKSe1eMGCpaUlaboWS_V1E3TqIGyo0NZopWgDHUMdIx1jHVMdMx1zHctYpVioJAA)

```
/-`,~    # full program
/-`,~$$  # with implicit args
 -   $   # remove the input from
  `,~    # infinite list 0..infinity
/     $  # and fold from right over the resulting (infinite) list,
         # returning the left-hand element each time
```

Answer (score 1):

## [*><>](https://github.com/redstarcoder/go-starfish), 100 bytes

```
v           v       /&~1+I]:&1[D>20.
>l:?!\:1[D&0>:}}:{=?/&1-:&?!\{$}^
;n   /!                    {/
```

This one's a bit convoluted, so I don't plan on doing a full write-up. The gist, though, is to keep the initial input length (IIL) on a stack above our main one, keep the current index (CI) of the input that we're checking in the register, and to keep a counter value on the stack, leaving it at the 0th index when it comes time to print it.

Checks for a value in the input by starting at the end of the input, and moving forward.

**Initialization** - The part of Line 1 & 2 I don't mention later

```
v
>l:?!\:1[D&0
```

- Ensure the IP is on Line 2, and moving to the right
- Get the length of the input
- If it's `0`, move down to Line 3 and print that
- Otherwise, duplicate that IIL, and put one copy on a stack above our current one
- And put another copy into the register

**Line 1** - Counter value is in input

```
/&~1+I]:&1[D>20.
```

- Dump the register
- Collapse the IIL down onto the current stack
- Push a copy of the IIL into the register
- Recreate the stack containing the IIL
- Move the IP to `[0, 2]` in the code, placing it before the second `v`

**Line 2** - Test counter == input[CI], and handle not equal case

```
>:}}:{=?/&1-:&?!\{$}^
```

- Ensure IP is moving to the right
- Duplicate the counter and input[CI]
- Move the stack such that a copy of the counter and a copy of the current index are next to each other
- If equal, move to Line 1
- Otherwise, reduce the CI by one
- Check if CI == 0, if so, move to Line 3
- Otherwise,
- Reduce CI by 1
- Move the last element of the input to input[1]
- Move up to Line 1, just before the jump to `[0, 2]`, essentially creating a `do ... while (...)` loop

**Line 3** - Print

```
;n   /!                    {/
```

- If we're printing from Line 2, shift the counter value to the end of the stack

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky5JLErLLM74/79MAQFgbH21OkNtz1grNcNoFzsjAz0uuxwre8UYKyBXzcDOqrbWqtrWXl/NUNdKDShcrVIbx2WdB9KnqIAFVOv///8vv6AkMz@v@L9u5n9DBQMFcwUzBWMFQ0MFQ1MFQwVLBSMQT8EUTJsA5SyAPEMLAA)

Answer (score 0):

### Perl - 34

Here's a subroutine.

```
sub f{$_~~@_?1:return$_ for0..20}
```

Test with:

```
perl -e'print f(0,1,3,4,5,6,7); sub f{$_~~@_?1:return$_ for 0..20}'
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java, 93

```
int f(int[]a){int i=0,j=0,k=a.length;for(;i++<20&j<k;){for(j=0;j<k&&a[j++]!=i;);}return i-1;}
```

Ungolfed:

```
int f(int[] a) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, length = a.length;
    for (; i < 20 & j < length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < length && a[j] != i; j++) { }
    }
    return i - 1;
}
```

Comment: Produces `-1` for test case `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 50

```
def f(l)
    for n in 22,if n not in l,break
    print n
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 74

```
i=-1;a=prompt().split(',');while(i<21&&a.indexOf(String(++i))>=0);alert(i)
```

Nice and simple! Note the empty while loop.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (E6) 35

Recursive function, array parameter in input and returning the `mex`. Not limited to 20

```
F=(l,i=0)=>~l.indexOf(i)?F(l,++i):i
```

**Test** in FireFox/FireBug console

```
;[[1],[0],[2, 0],[3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3],[],[1, 2, 3],
[5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7],[3, 2, 1, 0],[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
[1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 11, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18]]
.forEach(list => console.log(list, F(list)))
```

*Output*

```
[1] 0
[0] 1
[2, 0] 1
[3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 3] 2
[] 0
[1, 2, 3] 0
[5, 4, 1, 5, 4, 8, 2, 1, 5, 4, 0, 7, 7] 3
[3, 2, 1, 0] 4
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3] 4
[1, 0, 7, 6, 3, 11, 15, 1, 9, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 1, 18] 10
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
f!}TQZ
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=f%21%7DTQZ&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B2%2C+0%5D%0A%5B3%2C+1%2C+0%2C+1%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+1%2C+5%2C+4%2C+8%2C+2%2C+1%2C+5%2C+4%2C+0%2C+7%2C+7%5D%0A%5B3%2C+2%2C+1%2C+0%5D%0A%5B0%2C+0%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+2%2C+3%5D%0A%5B1%2C+0%2C+7%2C+6%2C+3%2C+11%2C+15%2C+1%2C+9%2C+2%2C+3%2C+1%2C+5%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+6%2C+8%2C+1%2C+18%5D&debug=0)

Makes no assumptions on the contents of the list.

###### Explanation:

```
f!}TQZ | Full code
-------+--------------------------------
f    Z | First T starting at 0 such that
 !}TQ  |  T is not in the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), <s>27</s> 17 bytes

```
$=>[min--@0..20&]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?INOQq5)

```
$=>[       ; a function
    min    ; minimum of
    --     ; difference of
    @0..20 ; 0..20, reified
    &      ; and input
]          ; end function
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 7 bytes

```
05²Ř←\↓
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f/fwPTQpqMzHrVNiHnUNvn//2hDHWMgNNQxiQUA)

```
  05²Ř           generate [0,1,2,...,25]
  ←              get input
  \              set difference
  ↓              get minimum; implicit print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java 8 (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 49 bytes

Solution using only inline stream :

```java
l->l.stream().sorted().reduce(0,(a,b)->a<b?a:b+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZRNT8MwDIbP7Ff4mIouWvcBg40ijkjjtCPi4LZplZK1U5IOTWi/vXhJCxLn1ooqx7Eev3oTtcQTTuujqMrssz02iZIppAqNgTeUFXxPJkAhKyt0jqmAHZWgC6pCzkoi8MZKxXfS2O0rtRZCx6CCjeu8eISxaIm9AwVPrZrGihurBR5YwE2trcgo0SJrUsFmIcMwCaYxbpNnfExuo6D1rE5gxzrVMoMDyWR7q2VVvH8A6sIEJPFmfzZWHHjdWH6kM6sqpnjOKvEFf4JftMazUx2zf1XD0VxPWBRQbAYEzoYGzkMYnLkIISKs@1K@GJo/NI9kzkeQuQph6TzwydpN@d2SPfe0RvDeTxn8Vmf9lXq7xnAs6m25cw8nug5buYEPfmDvn8@XrnHtRa29mO6ncWl/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 37 bytes

Only 4 bytes above the best JS solution :'(

```javascript
l=>l.sort().map(b=>a=a<b?a:b+1,a=0)|a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZLfCoIwFMbve4pdOjLd/FMWzR4kupg6o1hOVKKL3t3mhmEWktkY4wzG7/v2nXOmV1rGxSmvFplIWJ2SmpOQW6UoKgNaF5obEQkpodtoRzfRHJuUIHindSyyUnBmcXE0UmOPDxCCKcu2AbvlLK5YAtCsR0f/pOM@3THBNIFBumsCLAXUKWt3tFKX7vTpU4MZzl1adn6x/B3dN4GnYtFFoMSeV5nYSu4h7S7d/ZC7xv3a2y7de5vItqU6ovEpDdJx@/2lmhnc6PhKa6212px07amHgfYTND5eJhLVDw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 bytes

```
21r|^h
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=21r%7C%5Eh&i=%5B1,+0,+7,+6,+3,+11,+15,+1,+9,+2,+3,+1,+5,+2,+3,+4,+6,+8,+1,+18%5D)

This is my first answer in Stax, so I may be missing some builtin that helps.

## Explanation

```
21r|^h # 
21r    # range 0..20
   |^  # setwise difference with the input
     h # first element
```

Answer (score 0):

## GNU [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), 127 bytes

```
s/.*/ & %-,-0123456789#/;:1;s/%0*(.*)(.)(,.*\2)(.)/%0\1\4\3\4/;s/(.)#(.*\1)(.)/\30\2\3/;/ (\S*) .*%0*\1,/b1;s/.*%0*(..*),.*/\1/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYw7DsIwEESvMlIU5Fix1xs7P1JzAtqtEAjRJEiG62M26WbejF5@3N1z/ZaSyVvCCbVrXeAupn4Yp7mi5cxLpjpY421jfGNab6Xbk0JhSRIlkV6UVPoRPjaJQTqJtBCMXG0Db9Uh3NJt9x3NeFWqjoSplABGh4iEHgNGTJjBCvm3vT@vbc3FXf4)

Without the array limit, six more bytes are needed for the inner loop that handles the `99`->`100` case:

```
s/.*/ & %-,-0123456789#/
:1
s/%0*(.*)(.)(,.*\2)(.)/%0\1\4\3\4/
:2
s/(.)#(.*\1)(.)/\30\2\3/
t2
/ (\S*) .*%0*\1,/b1
s/.*%0*(..*),.*/\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

## Z80 machine language, 11 bytes

Base address of list in HL, length in BC.

```
AF C5 E5 ED B1 E1 C1 C0 3C 18 F6
```

Returns with mex in A unless it's at least 256, then never returns.
If you replace the last two bytes with `B7 20 F5 C8` then it returns with mex in A if it's at most 255 and with the zero flag OFF, else with 0 in A and zero flag ON.

```
    xor a
l:  push bc
    push hl
    cpir // 8086: repnz scas
    pop hl
    pop bc
    ret nz
    inc a
    jr l
```

The alternative above replaces `jr l` with:

```
    or a
    jr nz,l
    ret
```