# Eight coins for the fair king

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, integer

This is a "counterpart" of another puzzle, [Eight coins for the fair king](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/77750/44061) on Puzzling.SE.

You can read the above puzzle for the background. The details about this puzzle are as follows.

A set of 8 kinds of coins of different values are created, the king wants you to find out the maximum N such that any number of price from 0 to N can be paid with a combination no more than 8 coins and without charges.

For example, (taken from Glorfindel's answer). If a set of coins of values 1, 2, 5, 13, 34, 89, 233, 610 are given, your program should output 1596, because every number between 0 and 1596 (inclusive) can be represented by the sum of no more than 8 numbers from the given list (numbers may repeat), while 1597 cannot be represented in that way.

In a mathematical way, if the input is a set S consisting of 8 positive integers, the desired output N satisfies that for any number *n* between 0 and N, there exists x1, x2, x3, ..., x8 such that

$$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_8 = n \quad\textrm{and}\quad x_1, x_2, ...,x_8 \in \{0\} \cup S$$

Your goal is to write a program, a function, or a snippet that takes 8 numbers as input, and output the maximum N as described above.

Rules:

- Flexible I/O allowed, so your program can take the input in any form that's best suitable. You may assume that the input numbers are sorted in the way that best suits your program.

  - Please state it in your answer if your program depends on input order
- Input is a set of 8 different, positive integers (no zeros). The output is one non-negative integer.

  - In case there's no 1 in the input set, your program should output 0 because any number from 0 to 0 satisfies the requirement.
  - In the case of invalid input (the set contains zero, negative or duplicate numbers), your program can do anything.
- Standard loopholes are forbidden.
- Your program should run within a few minutes on a modern computer.

Test cases (mostly taken from the answers under the linked question on Puzzling):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] => 64
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] => 0
[1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] => 72
[1, 2, 5, 13, 34, 89, 233, 610] => 1596
[1, 5, 16, 51, 130, 332, 471, 1082] => 2721
[1, 6, 20, 75, 175, 474, 756, 785] => 3356
```

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest program or snippet in each language wins!

Comment: Nice puzzle, but I personally think that some more test cases would be helpful in order to test our submissions.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make input size a parameter? Brute force approaches will struggle with 8

Comment: @LuisMendo Brute force approaches don't run within a reasonable amount of time. But I can't find a way to codify this as a rule.

Comment: @iBug Do you mean you want to allow such inefficient approaches, or rule them out?

Comment: @LuisMendo I want to forbid them

Comment: @iBug Then the usual rule is something like "submissions shoud run within a minute in a modern computer". It's fuzzy, but usually good enough, because the difference between brute force and efficient approaches is very large

Comment: @LuisMendo OK, thanks. I've added it.

Comment: Brute force is still possible with your time limit of "a few minutes". A slightly modified version of my answer runs the last test case in 1m20s on my 7 year old laptop.

Comment: @Arnauld Clarified

Comment: apparently Brute had a little more force than appreciated, as it seems most  answers are calculating all possible combinations.

Answer (score 14):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>113</s> 62 bytes

```python
for i in[1]*3:x|={a+b for a in x for b in x}
while{i+1}&x:i+=1
```

Here `x` is the input as a set of ints, and `i` is the output.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/5foWCrUG2oo2Cmo2BkoKNgbqqjYAgiTMxNQDygsLmFae3/tPwihUyFzLxow1gtY6uKGtvqRO0kBZBoIlBUoQLMTAIza7nKMzJzUqsztQ1r1SqsMrVtDf8XFGXmlWhkav4HAA)

(Thanks: Erik the Outgolfer, Mr. Xcoder, Lynn)

Comment: [96 bytes](https://tio.run/##HcjRCoMgGIbhc6/iPxpZDnKrOQSvRDwopvTDsJDGsmi37rKTj/d7pjgPo7@n9LIOXLFQSWBVUenaVAsBNwZAQK@5KYWMait1V/UndwdDPLPPuZqdwHfAt91wv0SJleIEgp0/wf@umKaAfi5coTmDB4NbzUC0DHieRjT5HSyeraE0/QE).

Comment: `x=0,*x` saves 1 byte. Better yet, `x+=0,` saves 2.

Comment: [78 bytes](https://tio.run/##HYhLCoMwFAD3nuLhQmyNYKwaUXIYLSk@KDFISp/EePX42QwzY1Y7zboMgSRq87PpI1Kk3jFt0g3ZCJ95gQFQA9063ur7@PnqUfLoP@FXOfQJdZidbRbUds8xBMcZNAzKgoGoGfALlaiuOrdoa38A) in Python 2.

Answer (score 9):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/wiki/Code-page)

```
œċⱮ8Ẏ§ṢQJƑƤS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o5CPdjzaus3i4q@/Q8oc7FwV6HZt4bEnw/8Ptj5rWuP//Hx1tqKNgpKNgrKNgoqNgqqNgpqNgrqNgEavDFY1FWEfBEiRjiE/GCCxsCFRgDFRhYQkUMQZyzAwNoApAskBdpoYgVQZAZcZALSbmIK6BhRFUEVCBEVDOHKQYRJiYm4B4INssTGNjAQ)

Takes on average ~3.7 seconds to run all test cases on TIO on my phone, so surprisingly it is quite fast.

#### Explanation

```
œċⱮ8Ẏ§ṢQJƑƤS     Monadic link / Full program.
  Ɱ8             Promote 8 to [1 ... 8] and for each value k:
œċ                    Generate all combinations of k elements from the list.
    Ẏ§           Tighten, then sum. Flatten to a 2D list then sum each.
      ṢQ         Sort the result and remove equal entries.
        JƑƤ      For each prefix of this list, return 1 if it is equal to its length range, 0 otherwise.
           S     Finally, sum the result (counts the 1's which is equivalent to what is being asked).
```

Answer (score 7):

### Haskell, <s>56</s> 50 bytes

```
g c=[x|x<-[1..],all((/=x).sum)$mapM(0:)$c<$c]!!0-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P10h2Ta6oqbCRjfaUE8vVicxJ0dDQ9@2QlOvuDRXUyU3scBXw8BKUyXZRiU5VlHRQNfwf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQrpCtKGOkY6FjrGRjqGhIZgwARGmIMIs9j8A)

A brute force approach. Add `0` to the list of coins and try all combinations of 8 picks. Find the first number `n` that is not equal to the sum of any of the picks and return `n-1`.

Takes about 5m30s for `[1, 2, 5, 13, 34, 89, 233, 610]` on my 7 year old laptop hardware.

Edit: -6 bytes thanks to @Ørjan Johansen

An even shorter version (-2 bytes, again thanks to @Ørjan Johansen) is

#### Haskell, 48 bytes

```
g c=[x|x<-[1..],all((/=x).sum)$mapM(:0:c)c]!!0-1
```

but it uses significantly more memory and runs into heavy paging on my machine and does not finish "within a few minutes".

Comment: You can use `mapM(0:)$c<$c`. (In fact `mapM(:0:c)c` should work, but times out on TIO for the given test case.)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>100 88 80</s>  76 bytes

This is essentially a brute-force search, but enhanced with pruning to speed it up. The average execution time for the test cases is close to 1 second on TIO.

Assumes that the input array is sorted from highest to lowest.

```javascript
a=>[...Array(a[0]*9)].findIndex(g=(i=8,s)=>s*i>0?a.every(x=>g(i-1,s-x)):s)-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/NjoMgFAXg/TwFS2iQgsiPk@BklvMMxgWpaGganUjT2Ke3V7tpnC6G3U3Od8/l7G8@nab4e82GsQ1L5xbvqpox9j1N/o59zZtDSRrWxaH9Gdow497h6CxNxFXpECv@5Vm4hemOZ1f1OGaCpmwm5DORTCyncUjjJbDL2OMO15YiQ5GmSFFUUCQpyikSDSHo5R2PSBcfO1lS9Ab/lfxf8E2lyfdSCw4VEuIWlkiQQm47Xm8GKVSp91ZwC6nCCIByzUvYpWASzzM2DzY3udhbYyFglF79Wmq2EWr59olnNVgplV4e)

#### Commented

```javascript
a =>                      // a[] = input array
  [...Array(a[0] * 9)]    // create an array of 9 * max(a) entries
  .findIndex(             // find the position of the first truthy result
    g = (i = 8, s) =>     // g = recursive function taking a counter i, initialized to 8
                          //     and a sum s, initialized to the position in the above array
      s * i > 0 ?         //   if s is positive and i is not equal to 0:
        a.every(x =>      //     for each value x in a[]:
          g(i - 1, s - x) //       do a recursive call with i - 1 and s - x
        )                 //     end of every()
      :                   //   else:
        s                 //     yield s (s = 0 means success and makes findIndex go on)
  ) - 1                   // end of findIndex(); decrement the result
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
Żœċ8§ḟ’$Ṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///o7qOTj3RbHFr@cMf8Rw0zVR7ubPp/uP1R0xoF9///o6MNdRSMdBQUjIHYBIgVTEGEGYgwBxEKFrFcOtFAFTAFaPIWYEWWIEWGRCoygigwBCk2Bqm2sAQKGoO4ZoYGUEUgBUADTA1BCg2AJhsDtZmYg7gGFkZQRUAFRkA5c5BiEGFibgLigSw2tzCN5YoFAA)

#### How it works

```
Żœċ8§ḟ’$Ṃ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ż          Prepend a 0 to A.
 œċ8       Take all combinations of length 8, with repetitions.
    §      Take the sum of each combination.
       $   Combine the two links to the left into a monadic chain.
      ’      Decrement all sums.
     ḟ       Filterfalse; keep only sums that do not appear in the decremented sums.
        Ṃ  Take the minimum.
```

Comment: `Żṗ8§ḟ’$Ṃ` saves one byte, but I'm not sure if 8.5 minutes counts as *a few*.

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 53 bytes

```
LengthWhile[CoefficientList[(1+Tr[x^#])^8,x],#>0&]-1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY1NC4JAFEX/ygNBip7k@DXjIgnaumgRtBhGEBlzIA1sFoL42@1NuIw2D@495/L62na6r61p6rWFE6ylHh62u3fmqeXlpdvWNEYPtjRvK3fscBvlVHlqXwmcFHpF6KuA@et1NIOVHgQFtNJTCnw4nmGeGUKEECMkCClChsARxIIw/6gRckfYPxJ9a0ZCTIbIqYkpZCzcBEdplTJnhaTFNEm4i6GINomEiBh3sjsJT1xy30S6LOsH)

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 145 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
x=set(map(sum,reduce(chain,map(combinations_with_replacement,[input()]*9,range(9)))))
print~-min(set(range(1,max(x)+2))-x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwFET3niLLxEaoorUuehIRSW1aP5ifkHxpuunVU0NnMTBv4LkPrRablJ7eGgakPVm7BQbGWU9lEW9BEzfK8bAb6fVjXzRfVgUoM1ysuQMqAothfgOts9duU4s2GkmOgG4nLqZykF7hS/NB5BTOA9K3MoA86/9ffRgjj@LUCFFFkdJYS3aRrDlL1neS1bnavs3rwP21m34)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 57 bytes

```
a->n=-1;while(polcoeff((1+sum(i=1,8,x^a[i]))^8,n++),);n-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY3dCoMwDEZfJXjVYgrGn1kRfRFRKGNuBafFbWx7epcML8duQr7vnJDgVm/OYRuhgc2Zdm4M1c@Ln04qLNNxOY2jUhTfHlflG0KLr8F1vtd6sDjHsUZdz4Y2F8L0Vg5MC2H1853XSEIEo3JaI3QdIaQIGUKOUCAcEEoE2zP6USNUQugfSb81sZCxYStuMg4HSnZBKF8VJFbCWsYneSkxsekusZAyK0WWkZe5JPlmi77X2wc)

Comment: is this using generating function?

Comment: @donbright Yes.

Comment: that is awesome.. one of the few answers not brute-forcing the solution. alot of languages probably dont have built in polynomial symbolic features. Pari GP is cool.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>125</s> <s>115</s> 111 bytes

```python
lambda c:sum(i==j for i,j in enumerate(sorted(set(map(sum,product([0]+c,repeat=8))))))-1
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwDIbPy1P4mG6uRIAWWoknYRwYBC1VQ6LEHPb0zEY9TvPB0v//nxPZ8Ye@w1ruS/e5P0f/NY8w3fPmteu6BywhgcMHuBXsunmbRrI6h0R21tmS9mPUDGNMYd4m0n0xfEyYbLQjde3pqLNRSwoeHNlEITwzOB/5ifedbKYMHfSqNwglQoVQI1wQrggNQjug6v@wEW6SmP@S8rANAxUT7Y2disXVFC9AUp66GKEKxioeqRuRRVu@IAZKzhqBpdVNLUp@ay/MDErJiWQRudGx0F29xeRWgkWLPu2/)

Expects a list of integers as input.

Explanation:

```python
# an anonymous function
lambda c:
                                                          # get all length-8 combinations of values, from (0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) to (8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8)
                                                          # zero is added to ensure that combinations of fewer than 8 coins are represented Ex:(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
                                                          product([0]+c,repeat=8)
                                                  # for each combination, sum the values
                                                  map(sum,.......................)
                                       # get unique values, then sort them smallest to largest
                                       sorted(set(................................))
             # for each index, value pair, return if the index is equal to the value
             i==j for i,j in enumerate(.............................................)
         # in Python arithmetic, False is 0 and True is 1. So, count how many items match their index.
         # Since zero was added to the list, there will always be one extra match (0==0). So offset by one.
         sum(........................................................................)-1
from itertools import*
```

Answer (score 2):

## Perl6, <strike>65</strike> <strike>63</strike> 41 bytes (<strike>39</strike> 37 chars)

```perl6
{@_=(0,|@_)X+(0,|@_)for ^3;($_ if $_==$++for @_.sort.unique)-1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJZq@7/aId5Ww0CnxiFeM0IbwtArzcssLE3VTMsvUogzttZQiVfITFNQibe1VdHWBgkClRTnF5XA1Oka1v4vTgQZp2GoY6ZjZKBjbqpjCMQm5iZAppmOuYWppjXXfwA)

This is an anonymous block that gets passed its data as an array.  The `(0,|@_)` is a quick way to add a `0` to `@_`, and even though it's done twice, it's still a bit shorter than `@_.push: 0;` which would then need spaces after the `_`. This is a brute force approach that cheeses a bit on the fact that it's 8 combinations.  After cross adding, an anonymous list is created for sequential values.  With math operators, lists evaluate to their length, so the -1 pulls double duty: accounting for the 0 and coercing to Int.

This can take its sweet time, but by changing one or both `(0,|@_)` to `(0,|@_.unique)` before the first `for` it can be sped up considerably.  That adds **+7** (runtime <60s) or **+14** (runtime <10s) to the score if you feel the first is too slow (I did this for the linked code to avoid timeouts after 60 seconds).

**Edit:** JoKing in the comments improved it (same idea, cross add, then return the last consecutive result) to an astonishing 39 chars (41 bytes):

```perl6
{(@_=@_ X+0,|@_)xx 3;first *+1∉@_,^∞}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dc7PasJAEAbw@z7FIFKTOsj@y26CpKSH3nouhZCGHCIEUpXEg6Le7Uv04XyRdGbpsb0sfPP9Zth9O/Ru@jzBQ5tP56io86KG96XES1HHxyOY9aYbxgM8LtX99lXU@HG/fV@nzW6AqO@27RjDWQAAXZg3@Wrc990hmkH@BLN4zcXYnKCNLvOmlNXq5e35NcYF1wukkarEVUylQtAIBsEiJAgOwSOkFTNnRflHh5CFWgpe/q/1Wvzepk6RMsTSjCaGglMyKJVkLjhGdCFRjCVpQ5vWc5SpDlZ7rYIlp4l43uHHesuJP5AmgRqTuB8)

The final tabulation doesn't need a 0, saving a few bytes by only needing to add 0 in once.  The `xx 3` mimics the for loop (still cheeses on the coins being a power of 2).  The `first` sub returns the first number in the infinite list `0..*` (`^Inf` is possible too, but doesn't save space) whose `+1` is not a member of the cross added list.  Like mine, it's slow, so add **+7** for a `unique` after the first equals if you feel it's too slow for guidelines.

Comment: [48 bytes](https://tio.run/##dc7PaoNAEAbw@z7FEEKjySD7R3eVYLCH3nouBRHxYECwaaoJJCS5p6/ZF7EzS4/NZeGb7zfD7tuht9PHGZ7afLoERZ0fd93XsYWihveVxGtRh6cTmPW2G8YDLFfq5/5d1CijaHmbtp8DBH23a8cQLgIA6NC8yaNx33eHYAb5BmbhmouxOUMbXOdNKavo5e35NcQF1wukkarETUylQtAIBiFGSBAsgkNIK2Y2FuU/HULmayl4@VHrtPi7TZ0iZYilGU0MBaukVyrJrHeM6EKiGEvShjZjx1Gm2lvttPKWnCbieIef2MWc@ANp4qkxif0F). Technically, the `unique` is not needed, but it speeds it up a lot

Comment: @JoKing nice, I don't know why I didn't think about using `xx`.  I knew there had to be a way to do the final tabulation in a much shorter way using set functions, but my brain wasn't working.

Comment: The `xx 1` should be `xx 3`

Comment: @JoKing fixed.  Also I realized two chars (but no bytes) can be saved by using `^∞`

Comment: Actually, you can save some bytes with `(1...*∉@_)-1` instead of using `first`, (which I realise is the same method I used [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/173764/76162))

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>171</s> <s>145</s> 115 bytes

```javascript
f=(s,n=3)=>n?f(s=new Set(a=[0,...s]),n-1,a.map(m=>a.map(n=>s.add(m+n)))):Math.min(...[...s].filter(m=>!s.has(m+1)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lc6xboMwEIDhvU9x3Wz1csIYAklk@gSdOqIMVjANFZgoRu3j07t0q5KhHiyf9X@WP/2XT6frcFk2ce7CuvZOJYzOatfE114lF8M3vIdFeddmSETpqDFuDHqa/EVNrvk9RNck8l2nppeoee3f/HKmaYiKTXtz1A/jEq5inhOdfeLWcLo@neaY5jHQOH@oXrUGIUewCAVCibBFqBDqo9aHv@WdDGF3rzT/KfNbZhhYFvWObywPW5M9AFLzq6URlTGz/ERRyZjV@QPEIOe2EixbURUyye/qUsz6Aw) Port of @Mark's Python 3 answer. 108 bytes in Firefox 30-57:

```javascript
f=(s,n=3)=>n?f(new Set((for(n of s=[0,...s])for(m of s)n+m)),n-1):Math.min(...[...s].filter(m=>!s.has(m+1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 46 bytes

```
0//.x_/;Min[Tr/@FrobeniusSolve[#,x+1]]<9:>x+1&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdBNS8NAEAbge37FgFBqHLrf2aQ1JSdvgqC3UiSWFAM2hWSVQshvjzM1uUkvy77L8w7DnsrwWZ3KUB/K8ZiPUojV5V1snutm99aK4qk9f1RN/d29nr9@qt0dXh7Ufv@Yrbd0WYyh6kKX91GvEDSCQbAIDiFB8AjpgLCM8y0kNr6P@n8AQjYbyUTdJF5PRl@BImrIphm9GAqJkjNVLksmzJJmOcUNSRVDdes5ylTPBe21mgqENTnPRT6st5x4n9QNf9wYx/OH6KWtm1DER1Fc/2L8BQ)

Brute force approach: checks integers counting upward until it reaches a value that can't be paid for in 8 coins. Very, very slow (tio times out), but I'm fairly sure the condition is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 161 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
$l=:[1:_]#k=sort(nub(map sum(iter 8(concatMap(\[h:t]=[[e,h:t]\\e<-[0:l]|e>=h]))[[0]])))
=length(takeWhile((>=)1)(zipWith(-)(tl k)k))
$_=0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY6xasMwFEX3fIWgHiSQixw3bTBRpmQopFDIkEEW4dVRYmFJNvZzoaXfXlWh07mXe4bbOAMh@v4yO0M82BCtH/oRyREv@/DJd4DweLATLjInK1VUZ/3QySkZNMwf1MNAptlTi2Yka9r0oQF8g4HWqq1QS6UMv4e6NptcicrpH7OVrWZMKaET2EI6E27YUoTOnFrrDKVbyQpGv@1wsmnIGUVHOtYlOTtLEY8I6aAkGVEFJytOiueEFItScFKWS06eXu5VrJc6/jZXB7cp5q@HuPsK4G3zX94d4LUffczbuBJC@D8)